# How to check if a Magento product is already added in cart or not?

Tags: magento

I want to show popup when a product is first added to cart in Magento and don't want to show a popup if the product was added again or updated.In short, I want to know product which is going to be added in the cart is First occurence or not?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer largely depends on how you want to deal with parent/child type products (if you need to).

If you are only dealing only with simple products or you have parent/child type products and you need to test for child id's then:

```
$productId = 1;
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
if (! $quote->hasProductId($productId)) {
    // Product is not in the shopping cart so 
    // go head and show the popup.
}
```

Alternatively, if you are dealing with parent/child type products and you only want to test for the parent id then:

```
$productId = 1;
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();

$foundInCart = false;
foreach($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
    if ($item->getData('product_id') == $productId) {
        $foundInCart = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

The question was asked in a comment as to why setting a registry value in `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add` is not available to retrieve in cart.phtml.

Essentially registry value are only available through the life of a single request - you are posting to checkout/cart/add and then being redirected to checkout/cart/index - so your registry values are lost.

If you would like to persist a value across these then you can use the session instead:

**In your observer:**

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setData('your_var', 'your_value');
```

**To retrieve the value**

```
$yourVar = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getData('your_var', true);
```

The true flag being passed to getData will remove the value from the session for you.

Comment: I used "controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add" for getting product id before it added to cart..i used register variable for getting product id in phtml page on cart...and prepare one function for condition check as you mention..but now i am not able to get productid on cart page with registry..please help me for this..

Comment: Thank you so much Drew Hunter..A perfact solution for me..thanks for your help...:):)

Answer (score 0):

In order check if the product is already in cart or not, you can simply use the following code:

```
$productId = $_product->getId(); //or however you want to get product id
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$items = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
$isProductInCart = false;
foreach($items as $_item) {
    if($_item->getProductId() == $productId){
        $isProductInCart = true;
        break;
    }
}
var_dump($isProductInCart);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply..it was perfect solution.I used this logic in observer,now my problem is how to get $isProductInCart value on the cart page,as i want this value to show popup in cart page.i want variable value in one phtml file...

Comment: You can simply wrap up the above code within some function with product id as function argument and you can call it from anywhere.