# Magento: Is a certain product in the cart?

Tags: php, magento

On my list.phtml page, I want my PHP script to be able to tell whether any product is in the cart, based on it's SKU.

So my conditional would theoretically be like this:

```
$_sku = 123;  

if($_sku->isInBasket() == true){
    echo 'Product: ' . $_sku . ' is in the cart';
}
```

How can this be achieved realistically?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670419/how-to-check-if-a-magento-product-is-already-added-in-cart-or-not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetch all data from checkout session and check your product exits in Current  session

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();

$foundInCart = false;
foreach($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
    if ($item->getData('sku') == $_sku) {
        $foundInCart = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

it really bad to Check by sku.

Because of whenever configurable product cart then  simple product sku in db.

So you need to check using product id.for this case you need find the id of $sku by `Mage::getModel('catalog')->loadBySku($sku)`;  before start of products foreach loop.

```
$_skuPId='';
$matchPro=Mage::getModel('catalog')->loadBySku($sku);
if($matchPro->getId()){
    $_skuPId=$matchPro->getId();
}


$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();

$foundInCart = false;
foreach($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
    if ($item->getData('prodduct_id') == $_skuPId) {
        $foundInCart = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Code is plagiarised from this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11672465/2812842